# C# - Copying UnityEvent information using reflection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection, delegates

I need to copy the events from one UnityEvent to another, as once I figure this out I will be switching out the target at runtime to another object, what I have so far is:

```
MethodInfo info = UnityEventBase.GetValidMethodInfo (event1.GetPersistentTarget (i), event1.GetPersistentMethodName (i), Type.EmptyTypes);
UnityAction action = Delegate.CreateDelegate (typeof (UnityAction), info) as UnityAction;

event2.AddListener (action);
```

I get `ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.`, and if I change `Type.EmptyTypes` to `new Type[] { typeof (float) }`, I get `ArgumentException: method argument length mismatch`.

The problem being that I don't know what to put in there since I don't know what the type is (since Unity Events can send a bool, float, etc.)

Unity Docs don't cover this, so hopefully someone else has had success in the past.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using reflection and recursively copy every value field of the UnityEvent class. I wouldn't use this in runtime due to performance hits, but for editor stuff is very useful. I use one static helper class and an extension for cloning the list.

**ReflectionHelper.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CEUtilities.Helpers
{
    public static class ReflectionHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all fields from an object and its hierarchy inheritance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">The type.</param>
        /// <param name="flags">The flags.</param>
        /// <returns>All fields of the type.</returns>
        public static List<FieldInfo> GetAllFields(this Type type, BindingFlags flags)
        {
            // Early exit if Object type
            if (type == typeof(System.Object))
            {
                return new List<FieldInfo>();
            }

            // Recursive call
            var fields = type.BaseType.GetAllFields(flags);
            fields.AddRange(type.GetFields(flags | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly));
            return fields;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Perform a deep copy of the class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="obj">The object.</param>
        /// <returns>A deep copy of obj.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">Object cannot be null</exception>
        public static T DeepCopy<T>(T obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Object cannot be null");
            }
            return (T)DoCopy(obj);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Does the copy.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The object.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">Unknown type</exception>
        private static object DoCopy(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            // Value type
            var type = obj.GetType();
            if (type.IsValueType || type == typeof(string))
            {
                return obj;
            }

            // Array
            else if (type.IsArray)
            {
                Type elementType = type.GetElementType();
                var array = obj as Array;
                Array copied = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, array.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    copied.SetValue(DoCopy(array.GetValue(i)), i);
                }
                return Convert.ChangeType(copied, obj.GetType());
            }

            // Unity Object
            else if (typeof(UnityEngine.Object).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                return obj;
            }

            // Class -> Recursion
            else if (type.IsClass)
            {
                var copy = Activator.CreateInstance(obj.GetType());

                var fields = type.GetAllFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
                {
                    var fieldValue = field.GetValue(obj);
                    if (fieldValue != null)
                    {
                        field.SetValue(copy, DoCopy(fieldValue));
                    }
                }

                return copy;
            }

            // Fallback
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown type");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UnityEventExtension.cs**

```
using UnityEngine.Events;

using CEUtilities.Helpers;

namespace UnityEngine
{
    public static class UnityEventExtension
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Clones the specified unity event list.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ev">The unity event.</param>
        /// <returns>Cloned UnityEvent</returns>
        public static T Clone<T>(this T ev) where T : UnityEventBase
        {
            return ReflectionHelper.DeepCopy(ev);
        }
    }
}
```

And then it can be use like this

```
this.OnStart = target.OnStart.Clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I spent most of the day scouring the internet to help me write something. I ended up coming up with this simple function you can use. This will only work in the editor (but then again when will you ever want to do this otherwise?).

As long as this is a UnityEvent it will copy unity events with their parameter values as well (Objects, strings, ints, floats, voids, and bools) from one target UnityEvent to another on a different or the same component.

Everyone is welcome to download it and build upon if you would like. Check it out here:
https://gist.github.com/wesleywh/1c56d880c0289371ea2dc47661a0cdaf

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that stumbles across this in the future, this worked:

```
MethodInfo info = UnityEventBase.GetValidMethodInfo (event1.GetPersistentTarget (i), event1.GetPersistentMethodName (i), new Type[] { typeof (float) });
            UnityAction execute = () => info.Invoke (event1.GetPersistentTarget (i), new object[] { 180f });
            event2.AddListener (execute);
```

It just doesn't expose the copied listener in the inspector, so still on the hunt for a perfect solution.